# Move cookies from requests to selenium

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests

I would like to move the cookies in a python requests session to my selenium browser. At the moment, I am doing this:

```
cookies = session.cookie_jar
for cookie in cookies:  # Add success cookies
    driver.add_cookie({'name': cookie.name, 'value': cookie.value, 'path': cookie.path, 'expiry': cookie.expires})
```

However, I get some errors like

> AttributeError: 'Morsel' object has no attribute 'path'

How can I fix that?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to iterate over `session.cookies`

Comment: @pako Sorry I didn't mention that I'm actually using aiohttp ClientSession. As far as I know, `session.cookie_jar` is equivalent to `session.cookies` though.

Comment: `cookie.key` is your cookie name (according to https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/abc.html#aiohttp.aiohttp.abc.AbstractCookieJar) and other values you can access via https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookies.html#http.cookies.Morsel

Comment: @pako I think they might be interchangable since that is not causing the error. They mention that path is valid, but that is what is causing the errror...

Comment: @pako I might have fixed it by doing this `driver.add_cookie({'name': cookie.key, 'value': cookie.value, 'path': cookie["path"], 'expires': cookie["expires"]})`. However, when I do `cookies.items()`, I see other attributes like `domain`. I don't know if I should be adding those as well?

Comment: yes, domain is important for the cookie. Cookie is set per domain and path so all the attributes you should copy.